# Send Json Payload with headers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, format, payload

[I got this Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRzQX.png)

And I want to send it via requests with Python and I'm not sure how I can format this?

I will send them here just in case:

```
{token: "TOKEN",…}
   events: [{type: "settings_pane_viewed",…}]
      0: {type: "settings_pane_viewed",…}
         properties: {client_track_timestamp: 1655898468696, settings_type: "user", origin_pane: null,…}
            accessibility_features: 524416
            accessibility_support_enabled: false
            client_performance_memory: 0
            client_send_timestamp: 1655898469437
            client_track_timestamp: 1655898468696
            client_uuid: "UUID"
            destination_pane: "My Account"
            origin_pane: null
            rendered_locale: "en-US"
            settings_type: "user"
            source: null
         type: "settings_pane_viewed"
      token: "TOKEN"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing I have no clue what to do